# PHP 8 Error to repeated an Attribute: is it possible to use attribute multiple time?

Tags: php, annotations, php-8

I have an attribute as follow:

```php
#[Attribute]
class State{
    public function __constractor(
        public string $name
    ){}
}
```

I want to add multiple states into my class as follow:

```php
#[
   State('a'),
   State('b')
]
class StateMachine{}
```

Every thing is ok and I can access list of attributes as follow:

```php
$attrs = $classReflection->getAttributes(State::class);
```

But the problem is, whenever I try to instant one of them, an error thrown:

```php
$instance = $attrs[0]->newInstance();
```

The error is:

```php
Error: Attribute "State" must not be repeated
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the official documentation you have to define your attribute differently to be able to do it that way. I used PHPStorm to verify my assumption and this should work:

**Define attribute**

```
use Attribute;

#[Attribute(Attribute::IS_REPEATABLE | Attribute::TARGET_CLASS)]
class State{
    public function __construct(
        public string $name
    ){}
}
```

The important part here is the `Attribute::IS_REPEATABLE` definition. To make it work for classes you then also need to use `Attribute::TARGET_CLASS`.

According to [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/de/language.attributes.classes.php) you should also put everything in one line, when applying the attributes:

```php
#[State('a'), State('b')]
class StateMachine{}
```

Comment: Im trying to get these to work. Thing is , I dont want them to be repeatable, but its not throwing any errors

Comment: @theMyth You probably forgot to call newInstance(). Only then will they be checked for duplication.